# update statement in a stored procedure using temp table and real table

Tags: sql-server-2005, stored-procedures, insert

I've found many other posts here on how to do this but unsure how to write the initial select statement which checks for the system name and the update statement since there is a temp table involved.  I'm very green to working with stored procedures let alone temp tables so I'm at a loss.  What I understand to be happening is data is fed to the SP via an XML feed (that step is not shown here).  The data from the xml feed is then stored in a temp table.  As the SP is written right now, the SP inserts the data from the temp table into the real table.  I need to add a step that checks to see if the system name exists and if it does, update it and if it doesn't, then insert it.  I need help with the IF EXISTS select statement and the update query, please.

Here is the original statement which only consists of an insert.

original statement

```
insert into si_systemdetail(projectname, systemname, contactsbcuid, sdverifier, systemtype, location, proposedlivedate,  status, bkpsa, pripsa,platform)
   select 
        @project, systemname, contactsbcuid, sdverifier,systemtype, location, 
        proposedlivedate, 'Initial', bkpsa, pripsa, @platform
   from @systemInfo 
   where status in ('Production','Production w/o Appl') 
     and systemname not in (select systemname from si_systemdetail) 
     and @project is not null`
```

updated statement

```
IF EXISTS (select systemname from si_systemdetail WHERE systemname = (select systemname from @systemInfo where systemname in (select systemname from si_systemdetail) and @project is not null))  
BEGIN  
    -- update query
    UPDATE si_systemdetail
        SET  **I DO NOT KNOW HOW TO WRITE THIS SECTION**
    WHERE   
        systemname IN (select systemname from si_systemdetail)  
        AND @project is not null
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    -- Write your insert query
    insert into si_systemdetail(projectname, systemname, contactsbcuid, sdverifier, 
                systemtype, location, proposedlivedate,  status, bkpsa, pripsa, platform)
       select 
            @project, systemname, contactsbcuid, sdverifier,systemtype, location, 
            proposedlivedate, 'Initial', bkpsa, pripsa, @platform
       from @systemInfo 
       where status in ('Production','Production w/o Appl') 
         and systemname not in (select systemname from si_systemdetail) 
         and @project is not null
END
```

Comment: How do you read your own queries? Strongly recommend liberal use of indenting, carriage returns, and maybe upper-casing keywords. When you have a better format, use the {} button to make the code in your question prettier. This works differently than back-ticks (e.g. color-coding).

Comment: @marc_s! - Thanks for the formatting.  
@aaron-bertrand - I forgot about using braces.  Thanks for that tip.  I read the queries in MS SQL Server Management Studio.

Comment: Yes, I understood where you "read" the queries. My comment was about how much effort that must take if you fail to use indenting, carriage returns, and mixed case...

Comment: @aaron-bertrand it is indented in Studio, but just not mixed case (using Oracle will have that affect on you).  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can save one query by simply attempting to run the `UPDATE` and then checking `@@ROWCOUNT`. If it is 0, you can try the `INSERT`. In SQL Server 2008 you could replace this messy logic with [`MERGE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx).

```
UPDATE d
    SET d.projectname   = i.projectname,
        d.contactsbcuid = i.contactsbcuid,

        -- other columns here

        d.[platform]    = @platform
FROM
    dbo.si_systemdetail AS d
    INNER JOIN @systemInfo AS i
    ON i.systemname     = d.systemname
WHERE
    i.[status] IN ('Production', 'Production w/o Appl')
    AND @project IS NOT NULL;

IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0
BEGIN
    insert into ...
END
```

Not clear what you want to do when there is a match on systemname but @project is NULL or the [status] is not in those two values.

Comment: I read about merge but I didn't think merge existed in mssql2005?
Why do you have d.[platform] in brackets?

Comment: Yes, I didn't write a solution using MERGE because I know you can't use it (but hopefully you will be on 2008+ someday). Platform and status are in square brackets because they are reserved words. If you code your T-SQL in SSMS you should see them highlight in a different color. Best is to avoid reserved words; next best is to properly escape them.

Comment: Excellent.  Thanks for the explanation.  I didn't realize platform was a reserved word.